# Ajax POST request doesn't save data in database

Tags: jquery, ajax, database, post

I ran an ajax function to display the results entered into the form on the page.

Everything works fine and I am getting no error messages, but on page refresh all the data disappears. It seems to only be posting the data on the page without actually saving it to the database. Am I even doing this right? Thanks in advance!

```
        $('#submitAnswer').on('click', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var dataString = tinyMCE.get('addAnswer').getContent();

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/home/19/80/",
                data: $(dataString).serialize(),
                success: function(data){
                    alert(dataString);
                    $('.answer').html(dataString);
                },
                error: function(){
                    alert('damn');
                }
            });
        });
```

Comment: What is is your server side code to save to database ?

Comment: In `alert(dataString);
                    $('.answer').html(dataString);` it should be data  and not dataString i think but i don't know if it's solve your problem.

Comment: answer           = form.save(user = request.user)

Comment: are you doing `return false` or `e.preventDefault()` to the `form submit`.

Comment: I am doing preventDefault, yes. If I remove the prevent Default I still get the same problem

Comment: Can you put some light on it -> `$(dataString).serialize()`? What is dataString? Is it your `form`? or Is it your data string which you want to send?

Comment: dataString gets the content from the textarea. Edited the code above

Comment: One more thing If you can post the form submit function code here too.

Comment: added the submit function

Answer (score 0):

you can use web handles instead of ajax, I don't  think that .ajax can save data for DB. it is just get Data. for using  web handler see the following :

```
 $.post("AddInfoToDB.ashx?Data=" + Info, function (data) {

                    if (data != null && data != '') {
                          //Done
                    }
                    else {
                         // Error
                    }
                });
```

in the handler you can write your code of saving data